# Executor doesn't get called when a Promise is created in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

**Updated on March 9th**

I use built-in ES6 Promise and it works:

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Since I am sure that the version of mongoose is 4.4.6, it turns out that mongoose promises(mpromise) has something wrong. It is really strange.

---

I have tried in jsbin and it shows that the function passed into the Promise constructor will be called before the Promise object is constructed, but when using Promise in Mongoose the function doesn't get called.

The test code is here:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = mongoose.Promise;

// Test
router.post('/promise', function (req, res, next) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (re, rej) {
        console.log('start');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('stop');
            re('RESULT');
        }, 4000);
    });
    promise.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Nothing is printed in console.
The Mongoose version is `"mongoose": "^4.4.4"`.

Comment: promise.then missing.

Comment: @morels: Are mongoose promises lazy?

Comment: @morels Still doesn't work. Please see the updated code snippet.

Comment: What do you expect? Your route handler creates a variable with a promise that resolves after 4 seconds. Nowhere does it call `res`, so it will never send anything to the browser.

Comment: @Tomalak Originally i wanted to find some docs using mongoose, but i then found that some statements was never called which confused me. I replaced those codes with simple setTimeout and realized that the problem is due to mongoose promises.

Comment: Maybe Bergi is right and mongoose promises are lazy. Any reason not to use the built-in promises?

Comment: @Tomalak I have updated the code, but adding .then makes no differences. I know few about whether node has built-in promises so I use the mongoose promises.

Comment: Use the built-in promises. They work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between mongoose's promise and built in `Promise` is that **ES6's ones are newable instead of mongoose's**.

Mongoose documentation cites the "thenability" feature but does not mention any resolve/reject procedure (either [promiseaplus' docu](http://promisesaplus.com)), so nothing is expected to happen in your code.

A solution like below should accomplish your task:

```
var router =  require('express').Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Test
router.post('/promise', function (req, res, next) {
  var es6_promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log('start');
    setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('stop');
          resolve('RESULT');
        }, 4000);
    });

  es6_promise.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining :D